# Trying to get a variable equal to other variables in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  int score=0;
  int loop=0;
  int randNUM1=0;
  char randSYMB1=0;
  int randNUM2=0;
  int correct_answer=0;
  int answer=0;
  for(loop=1;loop<=10;loop++)
  {
     randNUM1 = rand()%10; printf("%c", "0123456789"[randNUM1]);
     randSYMB1 = rand()%4; printf("%c", "/*+-"[randSYMB1]);
     randNUM2 = rand()%10; printf("%c\n", "0123456789"[randNUM2]);
    printf("What is your answer?");
    scanf("%d", &answer);
    correct_answer=randNUM1/randNUM2 || randNUM1*randNUM2 || 
randNUM1+randNUM2 || randNUM1-randNUM2;

        if (randSYMB1=="/")
        {
           printf("The correct answer is %d\n", randNUM1/randNUM2);
           scanf("%d", &correct_answer);
           score++;
        }
        else if (randSYMB1=="*")
        {
           printf("The correct answer is %d\n", randNUM1*randNUM2);
           scanf("%d", &correct_answer);
           score++;
        }
        else if (randSYMB1=="+")
        {
           printf("The correct answer is %d\n", randNUM1+randNUM2);
           scanf("%d", &correct_answer);
           score++;
        }
        else if (randSYMB1=="-")
        {
           printf("The correct answer is %d\n", randNUM1-randNUM2);
           scanf("%d", &correct_answer);
           score++;
        }
 printf("Your score is %d\n", score);

  }

}
```

The code is for a simple calculation game, in which the user is asked 10 questions, which consist of randomly generating a number, then a symbol then another number, the answer is then stored, and then the user is told whether their answer was correct, and at the end of the 10 questions the user is given a score out of 10. My code seems to generate the numbers and the symbols randomly, and loops for 10 questions, but however, the code does not seem to take the IF statements into account, which then means that the correct answer isn't displayed, and thereofre, the score output to the user after every question is 0. Therefore, from what I can teel there is a problem with the IF statements, but I can't understand, what that problem is. I have also tried to use CASE statements instead, but the problem is still the same; the statements are not taken into account by the program. I cannot understand why the program does this. Is it a problem in the FOR loop, or is the probelm with the problem with the "correct_answer" variable? Please help!

Comment: Recommend a new set of numbers and symbols if code is going to attempt `/0` with `randNUM1/randNUM2`.  Maybe `randNUM2 = rand()%(10-1) + 1; printf("%c\n", "0123456789"[randNUM2])`

Comment: Tip: Until code is 99% working, suggest to comment out `// srand(time(NULL));` to debug with consistent numbers.

Comment: `correct_answer` in your code will  always be assigned with `0` or `1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code. `randSYMB1` will have a value of 0 to 3, none of which corresponds to the ascii values of /*+-.

Change the if statements to:

```
if (randSYMB1==0)
```

and accordingly to the rest. Also, you should never write something like:

```
char c;
...
if(c == "x")
```

You should use single quotes:

```
if(c == 'x')
```

This line:

```
correct_answer=randNUM1/randNUM2 || randNUM1*randNUM2 ||
        randNUM1+randNUM2 || randNUM1-randNUM2;
```

is complete jibberish. Move the calculation of correct value inside the if statements.

This:

```
      printf("%c", "0123456789"[randNUM1]);
```

works, but it's pretty insane. This is better:

```
      printf("%d", randNUM1);
```

I guess it's ok as a quick workaround for randSYMB1 but there's no reason at all with the operands.
Here is a working version of the for loop:

```
  for(loop=1;loop<=10;loop++)
    {
      randNUM1 = rand()%10; 
      printf("%d", randNUM1);
      randSYMB1 = rand()%4; 
      printf("%c", "/*+-"[randSYMB1]);
      randNUM2 = rand()%10; 
      printf("%d\n", randNUM2);
      printf("What is your answer?");
      scanf("%d", &answer);

          if (randSYMB1==0)
            correct_answer=randNUM1/randNUM2;
          else if (randSYMB1==1)
            correct_answer=randNUM1*randNUM2;
          else if (randSYMB1==2)
            correct_answer=randNUM1+randNUM2;
          else if (randSYMB1==3)
            correct_answer=randNUM1-randNUM2;
          printf("The correct answer is %d\n", correct_answer);
          if(answer == correct_answer)
            score++;
          printf("Your score is %d\n", score);
    }
```

Comment: Oh I see, so the randSYMB1 and all of teh symbols are the index values, taht makes sense, I'll try it with the integers, thanks

Comment: So i have tried to use the index values for the symbols, and the IF statements are now functional, but for some reason now the code does not loop

Comment: Thanks, the code works and it loops just fine, however, once the two numbers that were generated were 0 and 0 and the symbol between them was / , but when I put my answer in, which was 0 the program crashed, do you know why that may be?

Comment: It turns out, that it isn't just 0/0, but any number divided by 0, so I have decided to remove the 0 form the second random number, and change it to %9, from %10

Comment: Nevrmind, that breaks the code, but why does the ocde crash when something is divided by 0 and you input 0 as the answer?

Comment: Because you cannot divide by zero.

Comment: Yes, but surely, the program should discard that and output the correct answer rather than crashing, or should I remove teh 0s from both randNUM1 and randNUM2, and change it to rand()%9, for both

Comment: There is no "correct answer" to a division by zero. How you want to solve it is up to you. A simple way of doing it is just replacing `randNUM2=rand()%10` with `randNUM2=1+rand()%9`

Comment: I'm sorry i'm new to the site, how do i do that?

Comment: You press the V-shaped figure under the score to the left of the answer

Answer (score 2):

Benny, much of the difficulty you are having just stems from apparently just starting in coding. There is nothing wrong with that, if you knew it all already, then you wouldn't need to learn... (and you are never really done learning how to program, hardware changes, standards change, etc.. It's a journey not a race)

First, if you have the option, declare all variables before you begin executing statements. This will keep your code portable to compilers still using the C89 standard (all windoze versions through Win7), e.g.

```
    int score=0,
        loop=0,
        randNUM1=0,
        randNUM2=0,
        correct_answer=0,
        answer=0;
    char *symbol = "/*+-",  /* use a string literal */
        randSYMB1=0;

    srand (time(NULL));     /* now begin executing statements */
```

It's a matter of style, but if you open the spacing up a bit, it will make your code more readable (especially for older eyes...). While you can save lines by cramming two expressions on each line or using the *comma operator* -- don't. It just makes your code harder to read (for you and anyone else). Sure, if it is stupid-short, then you can get away with it, e.g.

```
if (!a) b = 1;
```

otherwise, put each statement on it's own line:

```
    for (loop = 1; loop <= 10; loop++)
    {
        /* separate all statements on it own line for readability. */
        randNUM1 = rand() % 10;         /* you have an int, use it */
        printf ("%d", randNUM1);

        randSYMB1 = symbol[rand() % 4]; /* get char from symbol string */
        printf (" %c ", randSYMB1);

        randNUM2 = rand()%10;
        printf ("%d\n", randNUM2);

        printf("What is your answer?: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &answer) != 1) {    /* validate ALL user input */
            fscanf (stderr, "error: invalid input - answer.\n");
            return 1;
        }
```

Next, the crux of your issues are how to handle the logic of checking the math operation and the user's answer. All of the logic is based on what random character was generated with `randSYMB1 = symbol[rand() % 4];` (my changes).

How do you take different actions based on a what one of a set of characters could be? Well, you can daisy-chain a whole string of `if` and `else if` statements together, or, just use a `switch` statement:

```
        switch (randSYMB1) {
            case '/':   correct_answer = randNUM1 / randNUM2;
                        break;
            case '*':   correct_answer = randNUM1 * randNUM2;
                        break;
            case '+':   correct_answer = randNUM1 + randNUM2;
                        break;
            case '-':   correct_answer = randNUM1 - randNUM2;
                        break;
        }
```

That leaves your a single simple comparison to determine if the correct answer was entered:

```
        if (answer == correct_answer) {
            printf ("Correct!\n");
            score++;
        }
        else
            printf ("Incorrect. Correct answer: %d\n", correct_answer);

        printf ("Your current score is:  %d\n\n", score);
```

(**note:** for division, the user must enter the result of what *integer division* would produce)

Putting it altogether, you could boil your code down to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (void) {

    int score=0,
        loop=0,
        randNUM1=0,
        randNUM2=0,
        correct_answer=0,
        answer=0;
    char *symbol = "/*+-",  /* use a string literal */
        randSYMB1=0;

    srand (time(NULL));

    for (loop = 1; loop <= 10; loop++)
    {
        /* separate all statements on it own line for readability. */
        randNUM1 = rand() % 10;         /* you have an int, use it */
        printf ("%d", randNUM1);

        randSYMB1 = symbol[rand() % 4]; /* get char from symbol string */
        printf (" %c ", randSYMB1);

        randNUM2 = rand()%10;
        printf ("%d\n", randNUM2);

        printf("What is your answer?: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &answer) != 1) {    /* validate ALL user input */
            fscanf (stderr, "error: invalid input - answer.\n");
            return 1;
        }

        switch (randSYMB1) {
            case '/':   correct_answer = randNUM1 / randNUM2;
                        break;
            case '*':   correct_answer = randNUM1 * randNUM2;
                        break;
            case '+':   correct_answer = randNUM1 + randNUM2;
                        break;
            case '-':   correct_answer = randNUM1 - randNUM2;
                        break;
        }

        if (answer == correct_answer) {
            printf ("Correct!\n");
            score++;
        }
        else
            printf ("Incorrect. Correct answer: %d\n", correct_answer);

        printf ("Your current score is:  %d\n\n", score);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
C:\Users\david\Documents\dev\src-c\tmp>bin\mathtest.exe
9 + 3
What is your answer?: 12
Correct!
Your current score is:  1

8 * 8
What is your answer?: 64
Correct!
Your current score is:  2

5 + 7
What is your answer?: 12
Correct!
Your current score is:  3

6 - 4
What is your answer?: 2
Correct!
Your current score is:  4

6 / 4
What is your answer?: 1
Correct!
Your current score is:  5

7 * 9
What is your answer?: 63
Correct!
Your current score is:  6

5 / 6
What is your answer?: 0
Correct!
Your current score is:  7

8 * 2
What is your answer?: 16
Correct!
Your current score is:  8

0 / 1
What is your answer?: 0
Correct!
Your current score is:  9

9 + 7
What is your answer?: 16
Correct!
Your current score is:  10
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

If never executes because randSYMB1 is number between 0-3, and not "/*-+". Also i suggest seeding random first, but in this case it doesn't matter.

Comment: What do you mean that ranSYMB1 is between 0-3?

Comment: @Benny rand() produces a number. You set randSYMB1 to rand()%4 - this is never set to a symbol. Also your || doesn't magically set correct_answer to what you want.

Comment: That's what `rand() % 4` must evaluate to, @Benny.

Comment: `randSYMB1 = rand()%4;`
randSYMB1 is number, its range is [0-3]. Thats why if's never execute. Didn't check for other problems in your code.

Comment: Additionally, @Benny, if you did something like `randSYMB1 = "/*+-"[rand() % 4]);` to assign the actual symbol to `randSYMB1`, then your `if` conditions would *still* be wrong.  The data types don't match -- you are comparing a `char` to a `char *`.  Use single quotes instead, e.g. `if (randSYMB1 == '/')`.

Comment: @bhow I tried that same line with another code, the line was "char randSYMB2 = rand ()%5; printf("%c\n", "$&@*^"[randSYMB2])", and thsi one was fine, but the one above doesn't work, and how shoul I change it so that it produces a symbol rather than a number, because it isn't working. And I don't know how else to set correct_answer to all of those options. Should I use more variables?

Comment: Ok, @John Bollinger, I'll try it with single speech marks

Comment: @Benny `char randSYMB1 = "/*+-"[rand()%4]; printf("%c", randSYMB1);`

Comment: Ok, so you switch the order, but could you explain why, please @chux

Comment: @Mare70 Code is [seeding random first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46798692/2410359) with `srand(time(NULL));`.  IMO, [not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798692/trying-to-get-a-variable-equal-to-other-variables-in-c#comment80544637_46798692) during initial debug.

Comment: @Benny Why did you code `printf("%c", "/*+-"[randSYMB1]);` like that?  `char randSYMB1 = "/*+-"[rand()%4];` follows the same idea.

Comment: @chux, that is how learned to do it the first time, and seemed to work, so i carried on using it, is it wrong?

Comment: oh, didn't see it chux. @Benny try to make some changes that we suggested, and then edit your question so we can help you further. that printf doesn't make sense, what did u wanted to achieve with it?

Comment: what printf, do you mean

Comment: `printf("%c", "/*+-"[randSYMB1]);` this one.

Comment: @Benny i can write you whole code for this little game. But i think you should first follow some tutorial. Just to get used to basics.

Comment: Well, from my understanding, doesn't that mean that one of teh symbols /*+- should be printed, and it is known as randSYMB1, and these should bde printed out randomly, this part works fine, and now teh IF statements also work becasue i have used the index of the symbols rather than the actual symbols, but now the code doesn't loop

Comment: @Mare70, I wish there was a tutorial, but I just started to learn C as a hobby, and was looking up tasks to do and this one came up, and looked pretty interesting so I thought I might as well give it a go

Comment: @Benny Edit code in your question, so we can find new bugs. Printf doesn't work like you think. `printf("Printing character: %c", x);` This is how you want to use it. text goes in " ", with %c for characted, %d for integer, etc. and after `,` is variable u want to print. There are plenty of tutorials out there, just google ^^

Comment: Ok i wil have a look at tutorials for random ASCII character generation, thanks, @Mare70

Comment: @Mare70 Please do NOT encourage editing the code in the question. That makes answers invalid.

Comment: @klutt well if editing is needed, that means answers are not correct ;)
I understand what you are saying, but i just wanted to help him, and there were too many mistakes. :))

Comment: @Mare70 Well, you have a point. But when that is needed I'd say it's better to delete the Q entirely and then repost. And in my answer I think pretty much everything is solved.